# Spacing between items in ItemsControl has been occured unwantedly while zooming using Slider

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

While zooming the ItemsControl with items which is placed in a Grid through Slider, I am getting gaps between the items at each zoom position. Please refer my below code.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ToolBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">


        <Slider Name="slider1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Maximum="2"
        Minimum=".15"
        IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
        TickPlacement="BottomRight"
        TickFrequency="2"
        Ticks=".15,.30,.45,.60,.75,1,1.15,1.30,1.45,1.60,1.75,2"
        Width="200"
        Margin="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        SelectionStart="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>

    </ToolBar>

    <Grid Name="grid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" 
                                        ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}"
                                        ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}" />

            </TransformGroup>

        </Grid.LayoutTransform>


        <ItemsControl Name="TabItems"  
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabPreviewParamsList}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="140">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Height= "60" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Red" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                        <Border ClipToBounds="True" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Height="60">
                            <TextBlock Text="Sample" >
                                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>

                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=TabOrientationAngle}"/>
            </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TabItems.Items.Add(1);
        this.TabItems.Items.Add(1);
        this.TabItems.Items.Add(1);
        this.TabItems.Items.Add(1);
        this.TabItems.Items.Add(1);
    }
}
```

While running the application with the above code and dragging the slider, some gaps between items is occurred which seems like white color border between items. Please refer below image:

[ItemsControlBorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUvUq.png)

Kindly let me know the solution to avoid the gap between items in ItemsControl while zooming.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This could be as a result of pixel-rounding in WPF, where both 'bleed' into the white-space resulting in the white line. This kind of behavior is often exposed by zooming, as it tries to compress things down into fewer pixels.

Try setting `SnapToDevicePixels=true` on your bordered/background items (or the parent ItemsControl, I think it trickles down).

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried your solution, but still facing the issue. I have tried setting SnapsToDevicePixels to true for ItemsControl as well the stackpanel inside ItemsPanelITemplate. But no use. Still I am getting the issue. Can you please help me..